# ASP.NET MVC Bundles debug = true and result is still cached

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

In my development environment the Javascript isn't showing the changes I've made, Why is it still caching, What else can I do?

The only documentation I've seen on this is the web.config, compilation debug=true setting,

Answer (score 3):

When you set `debug="true"`, the bundler will emit `script` or `link` tags to each resource individually, rather than a one for a single (optionally) optimized resource. As such, the resource will be accessed from the static handler directly by the browser. So, if your application or IIS settings have aggressive settings for caching static content, that would be your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not exactly sure how I managed to fix this, I notice firebug has a "disable browser cache" option in the NET tab, which I think fixed the issue. Seems impossible, but it's working so I'm not going to look into this any further.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force a re-download of content.  This should work in most browsers.